# UIVIew animation is not working properly in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview, ios10

The GIF shows the issue.
The below code display how I am adding view into superview and bringing up from bottom of superview. This code working fine in iOS 9 and not in iOS 10.

The animation of slide-up animation is not proper. It is coming out from right-side and making angle instead of straight from bottom.

Please help me to resolve this.

```
+ (ControlsView *)addArticleControlsToView:(UIView *)view bellowSubview:(UIView *)subview{
    ControlsView *articleControls = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ControlsView" owner:self options:nil]firstObject];
    [view insertSubview:articleControls belowSubview:subview];
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"currentView":articleControls};
    [articleControls setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[currentView]-0-|"] options:0 metrics:@{} views:viewsDict];
    NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[currentView(189)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:@{} views:viewsDict];
    [view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
    [view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
    [articleControls setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    articleControls.viewBottomConstraint.constant = -189;
    [articleControls layoutIfNeeded];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:articleControls action:@selector(slideSheetDown)];
    [articleControls addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    return articleControls;
}

- (void)slideSheetUp {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = 189;
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.scrollView.superview layoutIfNeeded];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't update the constraint constant in the animation block.

Comment: @Desdenova Removed and its working find but how to animate it now in iOS 10?

Comment: Keep the `layoutIfNeeded` bit in the block. Just don't set the constants inside it.

Comment: @Desdenova Not working

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this code**

```
- (void)slideSheetUp {
    self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = 189;
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.scrollView.superview layoutIfNeeded];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Hope it will works for you. ;)

Happy coding!!

Comment: what happen, same result as previous or any changes?

Comment: Right, same result as previous.

Comment: Your scrollViewBottomConstraint position (X) should be the same as redview at inital, before applying animation.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
-(void)hideShowTimerButton:(BOOL)show{

 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    CGRect yourViewFrame =  yourView.frame;
    if(show){
        timeContainerViewFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
    }else{
        timeContainerViewFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - yourViewFrame.size.height;
    }
    yourView.frame = yourViewFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please re-arrange your code like below it has not affected my view animation too much and solved my problem. Thanks you guys.

```
- (void)slideSheetUp {
    self.viewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.scrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = 189;
        [self.scrollView.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```